# Identifying K-means cluster instances - Python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am following a Kaggle Tutorial for K means in Python.
Just wondering is there any way to actually identify the instances that it have been clustered? So is there a way I can hover over a specific data point and its shows me the actual  instance ? (like WEKA)

[image: WEKA cluster assignment]

So it has placed each customer instances in one of the 5 clusters. I would like to know who these customer are, or to see the values of their variables. Pretty much I want to view teh cluster assignments per
instance

[Kaggle Code](https://www.kaggle.com/code/kushal1996/customer-segmentation-k-means-analysis)

[image]

Comment: In that tutorial - does it not mention something about `labels1 = algorithm.labels_` ? Or are you asking about something else ?

Comment: Thanks. I want to know how I can derive the labels . So each cluster data point I want to know which instance that is from the data ?  Just like WEKA does.  @ScottC

Comment: You can predict on the data to get it's labels, that'll give you a mapping of datapoint<->cluster labels

Comment: @SajanGohil  Thanks. I added an example from WEKA that allowed me to view the cluster assignment. As you can see when I hover over a cluster it shows me the instance of the cluster.